# Copy Python project folder to computer without python, can I run it?

Tags: python, virtualenv

So I develop a python application and I plan to copy the whole folder for my friend to use it as end-user.

But my friend does not have python installed in the computer and I don't want to make them install it since he is not a developer.
In my project I have set up the `virtualenv` with python.exe inside it but without the site-packages, and I copy the virtualenv together with the project folder.

Is it possible to do this kind of setup so the application in the other end runs without python installed?

Comment: Yes, there are several tools for creating executables from Python code. Note that if your friend has a Mac or Linux computer, they already have Python by default.

Comment: Make it an executable.  A popular resource is [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org).  Why doesn't he have Python installed? IS HE CRAZY?

Answer (score 1):

`virtualenv` is a good option if you are transferring the folder between two same operating systems.
In order to include the correspond site packages that are already installed in your computer, install them inside the `virtualenv` context by doing `pip install` in the virtualenv shell.

You could use `pip freeze` to get a list of installed python packages from your computer.

You could then include a `.bat` file (if it is a windows system) or `.sh` file (if its a linux system) so it would run your script with the virtualenv context.